# Is weakly holomorphic modular form finitely generated as module of modular function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let's use $M_k^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$ to denote weakly holomorphic modular form with weight k, level $\Gamma_0(N)$(in particular, k might be negative). Then obviously $M_0^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$ acts on it by multiplication since the weight will not be changed. Actually we know $j$ invariant is a generator for $M_0^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$.

My question: Is $M_k^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$ a finitely generated as a $M_0^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$-module? If it is, can we find some generator?

Answer (score 2):

For $N=1$ this module is cyclic: see the first two pages of [Duke-Jenkins (2008)](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/pamq/2008/0004/0004/PAMQ-2008-0004-0004-a015.pdf), which might also help to find the generators for $N>1$.

Comment: Here $M_{k}^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$ is the space of weight $k$ forms that are holomorphic on the upper half plane, but can have poles (of arbitrary order) at the cusps, so it is not finite-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I am considering weakly holomorphic modular form, not just cusp form. And in particular I am more interested in negative weight case, and this case is more mysterious I guess?

Comment: @JeremyRouse: You are right, I overlooked this. Anyways, I am keeping the second half of my answer as it was correct.

Comment: @user330928: I agree. Apologies for being careless.